# Strange trouble with HttpFilter while authorize the login

Tags: jsf-2, servlet-filters, omnifaces

I am using Omnifaces in my web application and currently use HttpFilter to authorize the login.

Here is my filter class

```
@WebFilter("/backend/*")
public class AuthorizationFilter extends HttpFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpSession session, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (session != null && session.getAttribute("userManagedBean") != null) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/frontend/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
        }
    }
}
```

The application is still running without any issues. And I also can access to `/backend/*.xhtml` without login too.

There is no error log, nothing.

Anyone have any idea about this strange trouble?

**EDIT**

Here is the UserManagedBean class:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserManagedBean extends TblStaff implements Serializable {

    private TblStaff staff = null;
    private String currentLogin;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean loggedIn;
    private ExternalContext ec;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{navigationBean}")
    private NavigationBean navigationBean;

    public UserManagedBean() {
        super();
    }

    public String login() {
        int isValid = doLogin();

        if (isValid == 1) {
            StaffBLL staffBLL = new StaffBLL();
            staff = staffBLL.getStaffByUsername(username);
            String destinationUrl = null;

            if (staff.getRoleId() == 1) {
                loggedIn = true;
                setCurrentLogin("admin");
                destinationUrl = navigationBean.redirectToBackend();
            } else if (staff.getRoleId() == 2) {
                loggedIn = true;
                setCurrentLogin("manager");
                destinationUrl = navigationBean.redirectToManager();
            } else if (staff.getRoleId() == 3) {
                loggedIn = true;
                setCurrentLogin("faculty");
                destinationUrl = navigationBean.redirectToFaculty();
            }

            return destinationUrl;
        } else {
            return navigationBean.toLogin();
        }
    }

    public static void setSession(String key, Object value) {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute(key, value);
    }

    public static Object getSession(String key) {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        return session.getAttribute(key);
    }

    public String logout() {
        loggedIn = false;

        ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ec.invalidateSession();

        setCurrentLogin(null);

        return navigationBean.toFrontend();
    }

    public void logoutAdmin(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        loggedIn = false;

        ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ec.invalidateSession();

        setCurrentLogin(null);

        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/frontend/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
    }

    public int doLogin() {
        CallableStatement objCall;
        SHAConverter hash = new SHAConverter();
        int result = -1;
        String[] params = new String[3];
        params[0] = username;
        params[1] = hash.hashBasic(password);
        params[2] = null;

        try {
            objCall = SQLHelper.execute("procLogin", params);
            result = objCall.getInt("Result");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: How/when do you set and clear the `userManagedBean` attribute in the session? Can you show the code?

Comment: Clearly `userManagedBean` is not null

Comment: @kolossus: I think my userManagedBean is not null. Because I used it in other place and it still work.

Comment: Are you sending a redirect after logging out? Check if the URL for `navigationBean.toFrontend()` ends with `?faces-redirect=true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared the `UserManagedBean` class as a session scoped JSF managed bean. So JSF will autocreate it and put it in the session on the very first occurrence of `#{userManagedBean}` in any page. This means that the `session.getAttribute("userManagedBean")` is **never** `null` once that happens, even though the user hasn't logged in yet.

Instead, you want to check its `loggedIn` property.

```
UserManagedBean bean = session != null ? (UserManagedBean) session.getAttribute("userManagedBean") : null;

if (bean != null && bean.isLoggedIn()) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

// ...
```

Note that the concrete problem has nothing to do with OmniFaces. You'd still face exactly the same problem when not using OmniFaces.